# Calling Function in Codebehind of aspx from Javascript Throws Error

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to call a function in the codebehind of my .aspx page once the window is fully displayed.  I tried using:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        PageMethods.CheckForPageChange();
    });
</script>
```

And it throws the following error:

0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined

I was able to get `window.onload` to display an alert box, so I tried using it like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        PageMethods.CheckForPageChange();
    }
</script>
```

But it throws the error "PageMethods is undefined".

I have this inside of a "form" tag:

```
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

And this in my codebehind:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public void CheckForPageChange()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Can someone please tell me what I am missing here?  Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: similar... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18242334/pagemethods-is-not-defined-in-aspx-page

Comment: The $ error was because you haven't loaded jQuery by the time it gets to that line.

Comment: pagemethods has to be static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined

Make sure that the JQuery has been loaded successfully.

> it throws the error "PageMethods is undefined".

1- You have to make your server side method as a static method looks like this

```
[WebMethod]
public static void CheckForPageChange()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

2- Call the serverside method like that

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function OnSuccess(response){
   //Do Stuff
}
function OnError(error){
   //Do Other Stuff
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    PageMethods.CheckForPageChange(OnSuccess, OnError);
});
```

3- put your script outside `<asp:ScriptManager>`, put it in a separate `<script>` tag

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the first error is that you do not include jQuery in your aspx page.

The next error properly is because you do not have `runat="server"`. Try to modify your `ScriptManager`like this:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManagerMain"
        runat="server"
        EnablePageMethods="true" 
        ScriptMode="Release" 
        LoadScriptsBeforeUI="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Comment: The OP has `runat="server" in the `ScriptManager` call. I think you mean to point out the `LoadScriptsBeforeUI` property.